How can Selenium (python) fail to see an element if I can see it in dev tools?
This is a general question about selenium.
When I open the dev tools on a certain website and search for an Xpath, I can locate the elements I'm looking for, so I know the Xpath is valid and does what I want. However, when running Selenium and using driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//valid_xpath_here") it keeps failing to find it by throwing a noSuchElementException. This happens only on a certain site, on which right-click is disabled on certain elements, so I suspect the site is doing something to thwart me, but Selenium also fails to find elements that I can right-click and inspect.
I searched similar questions for hours and read about certain elements being hidden, or behind iframes, but I don't think those are applicable here.
What else can the site possibly be doing to prevent Selenium from seeing things that I know are there? Is there some kind of javascript they're running to detect it? I'm using the uc mode Chrome driver from seleniumbase.

Without knowing the site you're trying to scrape and your actual code, it's impossible to be sure what the problem might be. Please elaborate Minimal Reproducible Example

You mentioned that iframes aren't applicable, but did you check for Shadow-DOM / Shadow-root elements? If the element you want is inside a Shadow-root, then it's not accessible via regular means. With open Shadow-root, there's a special way to reach it, but closed Shadow-root is inaccessible via JavaScript.

@MichaelMintz How to check if the page (or some elements) are behind a Shadow-DOM? How to get around it if it is? In one of the js files loaded by the site shadowRoot is mentioned a few times.

If there's Shadow-DOM, you'll see it when inspecting the element via the Devtools console.

First thought - timing.   Are you looking for an element before the page has had a chance to load properly?  I would highly recommend using WebDriverWait instead of pure find_element.

Second though - Shadow DOM.  Last I checked it's still not well supported but in most cases you should be able to fetch elements via javascript.

@MarcelWilson I am definitely allowing enough time for the page to completely load. There is no explicit shadow root in the source, but I do think there is an external js file that is making a closed shadow root around everything inside the body.

I would think you should be able to see that when inspecting the page.
